# Referencing a Userform

Tags: vba, userform

So I made a userform and ultimately I want to be able to add rows based off a number the user types into the userform. I have the code to insert rows, but I don't know how to combine it with the userform and what the person types in. the code I have now is:

```
Public Sub Insert()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual   'pre XL97 xlManual

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, 1).Select

    Set CurrentCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, 1)

    For n = lastrow To 0 Step -1
        If n = lastrow Then GoTo CheckLastRow
        If n = 1 Then GoTo CheckfirstRow
            ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Select

CheckLastRow:

Set NextCell = CurrentCell.Offset(-1, 0)

            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            For i = 1 To CurrentCell
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
            Next i

        Set CurrentCell = NextCell
    Next n

    'To be performed on the firstrow in the column
CheckfirstRow:
            ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
            For i = 1 To CurrentCell
                ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
            Next i
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question and code are a little unclear... what exactly are you trying to accomplish? You want the user to enter a number, then insert that many new rows, but where do you want them inserted and how many times?

Comment: if the user types in 5, I want to insert 5 rows. The location being under the selected cell. Thank you for your time

Comment: Ok, do you mean for this to be a separate macro? Your code for `Insert()` is not going to do what you just described...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You are Only Looking at taking the No of rows from user. I would suggest use InputBox. If you are Looking at Some thing else and want to Go only with UserForms. Try the below and see if it works.

```
'Procedure that triggers the user Form
Sub InitiateUserFor()
 UserForm1.Show
End Sub
 'On Click on Button on UserForm
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Call Insert()
 End Sub
```

Add a variable in Your Insert() to read value from UserForm

```
 Dim RowsToInster as Integer
 RowsToInster =UserForm.TextBox1.Value
```